# Django: увеличение количества товара в корзине

Tags: python, django, cart

Проблема в следующем: есть проект на Django, в котором реализована корзина. Если добавлять в неё разные товары, то все работает отлично, и из самой корзины можно изменить количество товара, но, если из карточки товара нажать ещё раз кнопку добавить в корзину, то создастся дубль товара в корзине, а я хочу реализовать, чтобы увеличивалось количество товара в корзине. Код прилагаю:
views.py

````
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product).save()
    return redirect('/cart')


@login_required
def show_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    amount = 0
    for p in cart:
        value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
        amount= amount + value
    totalamount = amount + 150
    totalitem = 0
    wishitem = 0
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        totalitem = len(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user))
        wishitem = len(Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    return render(request, 'application/addtocart.html', locals())```
````

models.py

````
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return quantity * self.product.discounted_price```
````

addtocart.html

```
{% extends 'application/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Корзина{% endblock title %}
{% block main-content %}
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    {% if cart %}
    <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Корзина Покупок</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3>Корзина</h3>
          {% for item in cart %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center align-self-center"><img src="{{item.product.product_image.url}}" alt=""
              srcset="" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail shadow-sm" height="150" width="150"> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div>
                <h5>{{item.product.title}}</h5>
                <p class="mb-2 text-muted small">{{item.product.descriptions}}</p>
                <div class="my-3">
                  <label for="quantity">Количество:</label>
                  <a class="minus-cart btn" pid={{item.product.id}}><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i></a>
                  <span id="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</span>
                  <a class="plus-cart btn" pid={{item.product.id}}><i class="fas fa-plus square fa-lg"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <a href="#" class="remove-cart btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-3" pid={{item.product.id}}>Удалить товар </a>
                  <p class="mb-0"><span><strong>₽ {{item.product.discounted_price}}</strong></span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="text-muted">
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Итого к оплате</h3>
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-0 px-0 pb-0" >Сумма<span id="amount">₽ {{amount}}</span></li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-0">Доставка<span>₽ 150.00</span></li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-0 px-0 mb-3">
                <div>
                  <strong>Итого</strong> <small>(Включая доставку)</small>
                </div>
                <span id="totalamount"><strong>₽ {{totalamount}}</strong></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="d-grid"><a href="{% url 'checkout' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Сделать заказ</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% else %}
        <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Корзина пуста</h1>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock main-content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать проверку, есть ли уже объект корзины для данного пользователя с данным товаром, если есть, то увеличивайте количество товара, если нет, то создавайте.

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    card, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(Q(product=product) & Q(user=user))
    if not created:
        card.quantity += 1
        card.save()
    return redirect('/cart')
```

Comment: К сожалению, в таком случае получаю ошибку при добавлении в корзину: TypeError at /add-to-cart/

'Q' object is not iterable

Comment: Если меняю Q на словарь, то далее увеличивается только первый товар в корзине, остальные не добавляются

Comment: добавьте Q в импорте
from django.db.models import Q

Comment: Решил данную проблему немного другим образом, def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    card, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user, product=product)
    if not created:
        card.quantity += 1
        Cart.save()
    return redirect('/cart').   Спасибо Вам за помощь

Comment: Советую использовать Q object в будующем, достаточно мощный инструмент для сложных запросов.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Благодарю за совет, ознакомился, правда полезный инструмент, буду использовать, ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение данной проблемы, только чуть-чуть другое:

```
def add_to_cart(request): 
user = request.user 
product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id') 
product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id) 
card, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user, product=product) 
if not created: 
    c = Cart.objects.get(Q(product=product) & Q(user=request.user))
    c.quantity += 1
    c.save()
return redirect('/cart')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]